# Blank function produces "object expected" error

Tags: javascript, function, object

I have the following tag in my HTML:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/formProperties.js"></script>
</head>
<body onLoad="alert('1'); setUrlParams(); extractQS('myForm')">
```

This will pull up a Javascript external script, formProperties.js, which for now only has this:

```
function setUrlParams() {
    alert("A");
}

function extractQS(id) {
    alert("B");
}
```

However, upon running the HTML I get the following error:

> `"Object expected: line 1 Char 0"`

I am baffled as to how a nearly blank function can produce such an error when I am definitely including the external script that has it.

I am using IE8.

Thanks.

Comment: please provide your complete HTML. What is seen in your question clearly lacks some `<` symbols

Comment: Use some JS debugger (FireBug or Chrome developer) to point exact place of error.

Comment: Try different browsers. What are the error messages in Chrome and Firefox?

Comment: Btw, consider updating your IE.

Comment: 1) We are not allowed to upgrade IE beyond IE8 nor use any other browser

Comment: I can't post any more HTML as this page restricts it

1) We can't use any other IE but IE8, nor any other browser

2) I can't even post the HTML tags I want as this page strips them out

3) FireBug pointed at the very first line:

    function setUrlParams() {

Comment: A web developer that can't develop (or even test) with browsers other than IE has a tenuous claim on the title. Anyway, keep in mind that few things in this word are less reliable than IE error messages. There's no reason to assume that the error has anything to do with that JavaScript file.

Comment: @user1544358 StackOverflow does not strip out HTML tags. You simply have to paste them in properly. [Read the FAQ.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: <html><head><script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/formProperties.js"></head><body onLoad="alert('1'); setUrlParams(); extractQS('id');">Stuff</body></html>

Comment: A web developer that is only allowed to develop with IE because of Federal US Government agency restrictions.. ?

Comment: @user1544358 please tell me you are making that up. Anyways, your code is fine. Try `defer="defer"` on the script tag or different computer.

Comment: Esailija: No I am not.  I wish I were.

Comment: The snippet of code you put in the comment is invalid since you didn't close the `script` tag.  We can't debug it if you give us different code.  I would also *seriously* talk to your boss about getting another browser installed on your computer for testing.  It won't get everything in IE but it will make development substantially easier.  Use words like "Impeding my ability to do my job;" boss-types tend to respond to that.

Comment: I have.. to no avail, because when you hear "Agency X does not approve of the use of any other browser but IE8 for security purposes", no boss on earth can do anything but comply.  I also did not type the entire code; I forgot the </script> tag, however, the problem persists

Comment: How about narrowing down the issue? First remove the `onload` event from body and check if page loads fine. If it does, start adding the functions into `onload` back one by one to identify what really triggers the error.

Comment: Comments like "upgrade IE" or "use a different browser" are nonsensical. How can changing the browser used by a **developer** fix errors for **users**?

Answer (score 0):

You will get that error if IE can't find either of the functions *setUrlParams* or *extractQS*. Check that the path to the script file is correct.